# Combining two datatables from different databases with ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am developing a wpf program in net core that use several databases.
One with some data, companies, users, countries...
The others databases contain the data of each company like customers, employees...
I want to link the customer table to the countries table in the main database, because I don't want to repeat the countries table in each customers database.
I use entity framework core.

The countries class in Companies Context:

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The customer class in Data Context:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

I get a List of Countries at begining of the main process that I mark as static.
Then I get a List of customers.

There is a way to fill the "Country" property in the customers list with the countries list?
I am trying:

```
var customers = Customers.Join(Countries, a => a.CountryId, b => b.Id, (a, b) => new { a, a.Country = b }).ToList();
```

But I get an error in "new { a, a.Country = b }"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit. I Use "new Customer { Id = a.Id, Country = b }" instead and works but I have more properties in the Customer class. I don't know if there is a way to create new Customer = a and Country = b.